# Choose a destination after drush cex

Tags: 8, drush, configuration

1. In my `sites/default/settings.php` I changed:

   ```
   $config_directories = array(
       CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY => 'sites/default/config-sync',
   );
   ```
2. I created the folder `config-sync` in `sites/default/`
3. When I do `drush cex` I get this message in my Terminal window:

> Choose a destination.
>   [0]  :  Cancel
>   [1]  :  sync
>   [2]  :  staging

What do I have to do? Because I want **all** my configuration files in `sites/default/config-sync` because this directory is tracked by Git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to execute the command with the "destination" parameter:

```
$ drush cex sync
```

as *CONFIG_SYNC_DIRECTORY* is the same as *$config_directories['sync']*

Answer (score 0):

You must define your config directories in `settings.php`, like this:

```
$config_directories['import'] = '../config/import';
$config_directories['export'] = '../config/export';
```

Now you can use these with drush:

```
drush cex export
drush cim import
```